# How to make a folder always to keep everything as unread?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, unread-mail

I have an unread folder in my Office Outlook 2007 account, the problem is when I select an item it becomes read, how can I make a folder that always force any emails inside it to be always unread?

Answer (score 7):

Right-click on the folder, and check the radio button for "show total count" instead of "show unread count." The color of the number next to the folder will be a different color.

Comment: +1 for providing a better option, rather than specifically what the user asks for. Keeping mails "unread" even when you have read them is not the typical use, so I'm not surprised Outlook doesn't provide this "feature".

Comment: For anyone interested, this feature isn't on macOS.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this post, I know it's old but perhaps this will help.

I just change my settings in outlook to not mark selection as "read" on it's own.

If I want something marked as "read" I have to specifically select the message, and the "mark as read" button.

IN 2010 go to Outlook Options | Mail | Outlook panes | Reading Pane...

choose the options you want.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a tool for this, and there's no rule setting in Outlook to mark things as unread.  You can probably make a macro or something to do a CTRL+A and CTRL+U in that folder (which would mark all as unread).